# Why split a string with only one space gets ['', '']

Tags: python

When I tried **split** in Python

```
" ".split(' ')
```

It returned `['', '']`. However, when I tried `" ".split()`, it returned `[]`.

Could someone explain that to me? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's been noted here, `' '` consists of two empty strings separated by a space. Moreover, `help(str.split)` would tell us:

> If sep is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

There's an empty string before the space and an empty string after the space.

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting the string at `" "` so you are left with a list of characters to the left of `" "` and to the right of `" "` which is both `""` and `""`.

See [split in docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)